# Finding the moment-generating function for a function of $X$

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be independent random variables with a normal distribution having mean $1$ and variance $2$. Find the moment generating function for $n^{-1/2}(S_n-n)$.

Umm. Our book doesn't have any examples on finding these mgfs. Sorry for spamming mgf questions lately, I kinda suck at this and our teacher did an awesome job delaying teaching this subject until there was almost no time before the end of lectures :( and the book does not cover it very well, even though the problems are messy.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the tips

- You [know](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moment_and_cumulant_generating_functions) the formula for the MGF of the normal distribution.
- You know that the MGF of a sum of i.i.d variables is the product of their MGFs.
- You know that if $Y$ is normal, then $a Y$ is normal for any scalar $a$.

The second of these points is immediate once you write down the formula for the MGF of $S_n$.